# selector property is not defined in template in angular 2

Tags: angular

Referring from this well written [quickstart tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html), I run my first angular 2 program successfully but few questions are in mind. Please help me to understand.

Here is [code snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fbu0gZCq70gviFkRfLLi?p=preview) and now my question is

1) In **hero.component.ts**; defined ***selector*** property in **@Component** Decorator

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: 'app/hero-detail.component.html',
})
```

But we did not write `<my-hero-detail>` in the respective template defined in `templateUrl`

and same for **dashborad.component.ts**, we have defined ***my-dashboard*** in selector

```
@Component({
    selector:'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/dashboard.component.css']
})
```

but did not write`<my-dashboard>` in respective template or any other .html page.

So What is the purpose/usage of this **selector** property?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I see you've got many questions, please seperate them to make it easy for the `SO`, `SEO` and `People` that are going to answer. Thanks

Comment: @A_Singh Thanks for the information. I did so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just a name for selector. we need a selector for a directive.
if you view the html source by inspecting the element, you can find `my-hero-detail` there. Angular insert the element for you when doing routing, instead of typing it by your self in templete.

Answer (score 0):

The selector defines how other components render custom HTML elements (for want of a better description). Its this selector that tells Angular which component to render.
In this case,

```
app/heroes.component.ts (current template)

template:`
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>My Heroes</h2>
  <ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
      (click)="onSelect(hero)">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
`,
```

So angular will look for a component with the selector my-hero-detail and render its template in the place of it, so the resultant output will be your h1, h2, ul and the content of the my-hero-detail template

Comment: yes but in your example you have written `<my-hero-detail>` but My question is that i havn't write this tag anywhere in page

Comment: How far have you got through the tutorial? You will add it to the heroes.component file. Just look for the section 'Select a Hero in the HeroesComponent'

Comment: that's the initial stage. later we add 'app/heroes.component.html' in `templateUrl` and there is no such tag. Please look for the code snippet i have mentioned in question.

Comment: OK, looking at the tutorial, the selector effectively becomes irrelivant. As per my code snippet above, that is used when a 'parent' component references it as a child (single instance). This tutorial then changes track and uses the component from multiple places, so its doing it via routing. Then its not selecting it via the selector but by component name

  {
    path: '/detail/:id',
    name: 'HeroDetail',
    component: HeroDetailComponent
  },

Comment: yes. That's why I am facing the problem. Thank you very much for your kind help. I see that selector are automatically added in view